# Fetching rows updated last hour

Tags: android, mysql

Every hour,my android app launch a service  to detect if a filed has been updated in my table, and if yes, a notification should be send. The table contains a filed called `status`, this field can be updated from `false` to `true`. My goal is to fetch and return all rows updated and send their values in a ntification.
I don't have a problem with service and notification but I don't have an idea to fetch the rows updated every hour.I saw some examples using `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`, is it a good idea ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way**.. Store timestamp and compare it with one hour ago timestamp. if it is greater than.. do what you want. As it is an `long` value you can easily compare.

**eg**.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();

String sql = "Select * FROM " + TableUpload_INFO + " WHERE " + updated_time + " > " + time ;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, so `DATE_SUB`, is a way to have a result ?

Comment: actually, i never used that...so, no idea. But i have used the timestamp to 
compare.. today or yesterday data.